# How to modify a CSS tag value dynamically using javascript

Tags: css, webkit, webkit-perspective

### Perspective based rotation : I have a div which i want to rotate in CSS3 using webkit. The div is rotated after a usermouse down event in jquery

I use keyframes to do that

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {

enter code here

0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

}100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

}

}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate2 {

0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);  
}100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);  
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate3 {

0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate4 {

0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
}100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

}
```

**My question is I have also applied webkit perspective to give a 3d kind of view and I have to rotate the div keeping the perspective X angle to 45deg...how is it possible ?**

```
body {
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-perspective: 500;
   -webkit-perspective-origin: 45%;
}


#mydiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #D3DAED;
  position:absolute;
  top:29%; 
  left:45%;
  **-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);**
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand exactly what you are trying to do, but in jquery you can alter css dynamically like this:

```
$('#mydiv').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateX(45deg)');
```

Comment: Changed `$(#mydiv)` to `$('#mydiv')`

Comment: yeah rotateX(45deg) will apply the webkit perspective and gives a 3d look.. but it will not rotate the div at angle 45 degrees

Comment: @user1184100 - so you aren't asking how to modify the CSS in JS/jquery as per the title in the question? rather which CSS to substitute in order to make your CSS correct?

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots => Image 1 :: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/tilt1m.jpg/                    Image 2 :: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/tilt2.jpg/          First image has tilt effect .. but i want the tilt effect to be there when the image is rotated 45degrees.. 2nd image does not have tilted effect but has been rotated 45deg

Comment: Thank you..got it now i'm concatenating the transforms .. -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotate(90deg);